# Select2 Tags replace spaces with underscores

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 JavaScript that does my tags.  The client decided that they wanted to have a space.  As you know spaces ruin everything so we compromised with an underscore but we wanted to replace all spaces with an underscore just in case not everyone follows instructions.
So I added a little JavaScript, but when I save new values to their assigned attributes select2 breaks, and it seems to be two lines of code that is breaking the process.

**Is there any other way to write these two lines?**

My JavaScript (I will mark the ones that are messing up the program))

```
<script>

    $("#tags").select2({
        placeholder: "Add Tag(s)...",
        tags: true
    });

    $('#tags').change(function() {
        var self = this;
            $(self).find('option').each(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var text = $(this).text();
                var newValue = value.split(' ').join('_');
                var newText = text.split(' ').join('_');
                $(this).val(newValue); // This line overrides the tag manually input before it.
                $(this).text(newText);
                    $('.select2-selection__choice').each(function() {
                        var title = $(this).attr('title');
                        var newTitle = title.split(' ').join('_');
                        $(this).val(newTitle)
                        $(this).text(newTitle); //This line deletes the x in the tags
                    });
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the text and value on select field change, you can do it like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#tags').change(function() {
      $(this).find('option').each(function() {
          var value = $(this).val();
          var text = $(this).text();
          $(this).val(value.split(' ').join('_'))
          $(this).text(text.split(' ').join('_'))
      });
  });
});
```

Here's a [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mipw0f113sagh0WcRk16?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  However, it is still messing up my tags.  If I enter in one two. It replaces it with one_two but then I want to have another tag like three four, one_two is replaces with three four.  It happens so far with everything I have tried.

Comment: Can you edit the plunkr to show what is exactly happening. I've tried it, but it works fine for me, see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mipw0f113sagh0WcRk16?p=preview